# what to know little about the arguments for given code .....?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.selector:contains("'+ filterText +'")').show()
```

for showing div based on the bases of string **"search"** now it's working fine with the exact character case of lowercase and upper case

now here i googled my issue many links i found and in almost all sites and event stackoverflow i found similar code like below code..

```
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())> -1;
};
```

so here i am interested in this `a`, `i`, and `m` parameters

also that how can i use the `$(".selector":contains('"+ search +"')).show()` with any case sensitivity `( lowercase or upper case )`.

the use this code with what i have written will be better one

and alternative solutions about free text search with key press will be the best on but but but

no use of third party plugins.

i think You guys need to refer bellow link 
http://jsfiddle.net/potherca/ympBL/

Comment: I don't know for what the hell you need this, but if you write `console.log(a, i, m)`, you can see if it's elements, strings, objects, etc.

Comment: Sure your first snippet works?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I think that it don't works. It's because of this I said what the hell.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown yes i am dam sure

Comment: It should throw a syntax exception. That isn't possible in javascript.

Comment: I am even more sure that it cannot work ... there is no `:` operator for strings in Javascript

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown : operator is used in jQuery  that's why i have tagged both jquery and javascript

Comment: The first one should be `$(".selector:contains('"+ search +"')").show()`

Comment: @lshettyl i knw now i want to use this with any cases but how.?

Comment: I know what you're trying to do, but you're doing it wrong. @Ishettyl is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to filter an element that contains the give text. One form is the following.

```
$(".selector:contains('"+ search +"')").show();
```

But this is case sensitive. If you'd like a case insensitive match, you may want to write a custom filter method by extending the filter expressions of jQuery, like below.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    icontains: function(elem, index, arr){
        return jQuery(elem).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(arr[3].toLowerCase()) !== -1
    }
});
```

> In the method you create for any jQuery expression, you are given three arguments. The first is the DOM element for that particular iteration. Second is the index of the DOM element relative to the original collection the expression was called on. Last is an array similar to what you'd get from a RegExp exec method call. The full expression is the first array position, second is the text from the selector between the colon and opening paren, and the last is the string that occurs within the parens.

Then use it as:

```
$(".selector:icontains('" + search + "')").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you learn to use `filter(fn)` which offers lots of control over how you filter elements.

```
$(".selector").filter(function(){
     return $(this).toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) >-1;
}).show();
```